# How to send a photo with .webp extension via telegram bot

Tags: telegram-bot, photo, webp

When I try to send such a photo, I get an error:

example:
`bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=test.webp)`

but i use links (hope it doesn't affect)

```
ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: wrong type of the web page content"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the proper path of the file.

```
photo_url <- "https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.webp"
bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=photo_url)
```